# How to return const type in a static method?

Tags: c++

I understand this is caused by const type `self.at(idx)` but don't know how to fix it in such a static method.

```
template<class Key, class Val>
struct map_item
{
    typedef std::map<Key,Val> Map;

    static Val& get(Map const& self, const Key idx) { return self.at(idx); }
} // is it legal to be static? but I need 'static'
```

Error：

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::basic_string<char>&’ from expression of type ‘const mapped_type {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’
  static Val& get(Map const& self, const Key idx) { return self.at(idx); }
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You should post the line where the error comes from.

Comment: @texasbruce: He did.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit He did not. He needs to provide the construction  of the template, e.g. where the std::string comes from

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit A wrapper using libboost. I messed with something else so I didn't notice I fixed the problem (I believed I didn't).

Comment: @texasbruce: He did and no he doesn't. `std::map<K,V>::at(const K&) const` returns a `const V&`, not a `V&`. Simple as that.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit OK maybe you can telepath how he constructs instantiation of the template and how he calls the get function, but I cannot.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/HowTo#std::C.2B-.2B-_container the sample code actually did worse.

Comment: @texasbruce: You are simply wrong. Telepathy has absolutely nothing to do with it. How he instantiates the template has nothing to do with it. And how he calls the `get` function has nothing to do with it. The semantics of `std::map` are specified by the standard. Everything you need to answer this question is in the question... and the standard.

Comment: @knh170: Yikes! Well that's what happens when you get Whython developers to write C++ :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fix the return type:

```
static const Val& get(Map const& self, const Key idx) { return self.at(idx); }
//     ^^^^^
```

The explanation is all in the error message you posted (added emphasis):

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type **`‘std::basic_string<char>&’`** from expression of type ‘const mapped_type {aka **`const std::basic_string<char>`**}’

`at()` returns a `const Val&`, but you were trying to return a `Val&` and there is no such implicit conversion. You just have to change the return type of your `get()` to match the return type of `at()`.

Comment: @vsoftco Because `self` is `Map const&`, not `Map&`.

Comment: You are right, I tried, just missed with something else.